# pdomenu modx изменение последовательности ресурсов

Tags: modx

Как изменить последовательность ресурсов в вызове pdomenu?

```
[[pdoMenu?
     &parents=`0`
     &level=`2`
     &resources=`8,30,24,29,449,389,  10,426,425`
                                    
     &firstClass=``
     &lastClass=``
                                    
     &tplOuter=`@INLINE <div class="footer__lists-col">[[+wrapper]]</div>`
     &tpl=`@INLINE <ul class="footer__list"><h3 class="footer__list-title" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</h3>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
     &tplInner=`@INLINE <div class="footer__list-col">[[+wrapper]]</div>`
     &tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li class="footer__list-item"><a href="[[+link]]" class="footer__list-link" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
]]
```

CODE:

```
                    <div class="footer__lists-col">
                        <ul class="footer__list">
                            <h3 class="footer__list-title">1</h3>

                            <div class="footer__list-items">
                                <div class="footer__list-col">
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.4</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.5</a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>

                                <div class="footer__list-col">
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.6</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.7</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.8</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.9</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">1.9</a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="footer__list">
                            <h3 class="footer__list-title">2</h3>

                            <div class="footer__list-items">
                                <div class="footer__list-col">
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">2.1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">2.2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">2.3</a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>

                                <div class="footer__list-col">
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">2.4</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer__list-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="footer__list-link">2.5</a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Переставить их в  последовательности...

Comment: @Николай, спасибо, я вас услышал

Comment: @Николай, не подскажите как вывести вот такое меню, я выше прикрепил, проблема с выводом 2 колонок с классом footer__list-col

Comment: &tpl_N
Имя чанка для N-го ресурса, например, &tpl_4=`tpl4th` установит шаблон для 4-го ресурса.
&tpl_nN
Имя чанка для каждого N-го ресурса, например, &tpl_n4=`tplEvery4th` будет применено к каждому 4-му ресурсу.

Comment: Или использовать счётчики и операторы